# Prevent image auto resizing on MPDF when outside of right margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I have a tool in my website where people can upload pictures and drag them in any place of the label area. When they press Save button, the PDF file is created (I'm using for this php based MPDF module).

The problem is with dragging the picture outside of the label area margins. What is the most confusing that this problem is only with **right** margin.

Here is the examples -
1.1) **Left** side of **HTML label** area in my website (image is dragged outside of left side):
[image]

1.2) **Left** side of created **PDF File** (image is dragged outside of left side):
[image]

**Works perfectly!**

And the example of problem -

2.1) **Right** side of **HTML label** area in my website (image is dragged outside of right side):
[image]

2.2) **Right** side of created **PDF File** (image is dragged outside of right side):
[image]

And suddenly it does NOT work. Image is auto resized to smaller in the middle of PDF generating process instead of just dragging it outside of the right side.

HTML code that is converted to PDF (this example):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html {
                position: relative;
            }
            body {
                background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                position: relative;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 82mm;
                height: 106mm;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="z-index: 11; position: absolute; top: 20.1mm; left: 26.4mm;">
            <img src="labels/80/images/image1.jpg" style="width: 125.6mm; height: 62.4mm;" data-new_src="labels/80/images/image1.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please add your code or JSFiddle?

Comment: Updated question with HTML code

Comment: do you have stylesheet?

Comment: Update: replaced stylesheet link with style code